# sessions not being set in all pages on php5

Tags: php

I am using session_start(); at the top of my login page. After a user logs in, a message is displayed on screen which shows that the session is being set. But, I cannot carry sessions from page to page or can I echo out SID. It is a blank value. I would be grateful if someone could show me where I am going wrong. Thanks

```
<?php

  $userpost = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

  if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user'] = $userpost;
}

   echo $_SESSION['user'] .' '. 'Just logged in' .  SID;
   // Or maybe pass along the session id, if needed

?>
```

Comment: You say you've to session_start() at the top of your login page, you'll need it on every page where you're using $_SESSION.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have `session_start();` on the very top of your code, after `<?php`. Since you are checking if the session is set without starting the sessions, your code will fail.

Is has to be like this:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $userpost = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

 if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   $_SESSION['user'] = $userpost;
 }

 echo $_SESSION['user'] .' '. 'Just logged in' .  SID;
 // Or maybe pass along the session id, if needed

?>
```

Comment: Devator, it is still not displaying the SID. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: @bollo if you wish to display the session id, then 1) you have to `define` SID, or use `echo session_id();`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're always looking in `$_POST` for your user data.

Bring the `session_start()` out of that condition:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $userpost = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

  if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   $_SESSION['user'] = $userpost;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You said that you called `session_start()` at the top of your login page, but you did not mention your other pages.  `session_start()` needs to be called at the top of every page in your application.  I generally put my `session_start()` logic, along with a snippet of code for logging the user out after a period of inactivity, in an include file and then include it at the top of every page.

```
<?  session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION["last_activity"]) && (isset($_SESSION["username"])) && ((time() - $_SESSION["last_activity"]) > 900))
    {
        unset($_SESSION["username"]);
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["last_activity"] = time();
    }
?>
```

Comment: William what is last_activity?

Comment: @bollo, sorry for the length between your question and my response.  In case you never figured it out, last_activity is just a session variable that I create to keep track of the last time a page was loaded in the session.  I check it each time a page is loaded and, if the user hasn't loaded a page in a while (in this case, 900 seconds), I log them off and make them log back in as a bit of security.